# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. error in set up of rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

p.s. : I am using ruby version 2.2.4

when i run the command in other directory like

```
letsventure-MacBook-Pro:~ letsventure$ rails -v
#~> Rails 5.0.1
```

it gives the correct output of rails version .

while in project directory it gives  output like this

```
letsventure-MacBook-Pro:lv2 letsventure$ rails -v
```

> Could not find mysql2-0.4.10 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

so i run bundle install

I got this error
[This is image link to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFims.png)

can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you please format the error better, as well as try to condense the error message?

Comment: Have you installed mysql on your computer?

Comment: @demir yeah i already install mysql and mysql2-0.4.10 present in my gem list.

Comment: @Xcoder   main errror is this one    after run bundle install                                         Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/letsventure/lv2/.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/ext/mysql2

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160961/2190621

Comment: @demir I am getting same error after  performing all the step in given solution.