# ld: library not found for -lzstd while bundle install for mysql2 gem Ruby on macOS Big Sur 11.4 Apple M1

Tags: mysql, ruby, bundler, macos-big-sur, mysql2

while running bundle install

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Rails app 6.1.3**

**Bundler version 2.2.19**

**macOS Big Sur 11.4**

**Apple M1**

in the Gemfile

```
ruby '2.6.6'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.1'
gem 'mysql2'
```

in the Gemfile.lock mysql is at 0.5.3

when I run `bundle install` it crashes with the normal:

[image]

Examining the build error, which appears earlier in the output,  the build error appears to be: (full results below)

```
 ld: library not found for -lzstd
```

The full results from `bundle install` are

```
jason@MacBook-Air  % bundle install    
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Using rake 13.0.3
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using rack 2.2.3
Using nio4r 2.5.7
Using builder 3.2.4
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using mini_portile2 2.5.1
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using crass 1.0.6
Using thor 1.1.0
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using aws-eventstream 1.1.1
Using aws-partitions 1.447.0
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.16
Using betterlorem 0.1.2
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.4.2
Using popper_js 1.16.0
Using ffi 1.15.0
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using bundler 2.2.19
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 2.1.1
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using connection_pool 2.2.5
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using diff-lcs 1.4.4
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Using docile 1.3.5
Using e2mmap 0.1.0
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using ffaker 2.18.0
Using finishing_moves 1.0.1
Using raabro 1.4.0
Using temple 0.8.2
Using sexp_processor 4.15.2
Using hashdiff 1.0.1
Using hiredis 0.6.3
Using honeybadger 4.8.0
Using kaminari-core 1.2.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Fetching mysql2 0.5.3
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using parslet 1.8.2
Using puma 3.12.6
Using rails_http_options 0.1.0
Using redis 4.2.5
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using semantic_range 3.0.0
Using rspec-support 3.10.2
Using simple-random 1.0.3
Using simplecov-html 0.12.3
Using simplecov_json_formatter 0.1.2
Using spring 2.1.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using stripe 5.32.1
Using vcr 6.0.0
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using warden 1.2.9
Using rack-attack 6.5.0
Using rack-cors 1.1.1
Using rack-protection 2.1.0
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using sitemap_generator 6.1.2
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 10.2.4.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.2.3
Using bootsnap 1.7.4
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using crack 0.4.5
Using unf 0.1.4
Using haml 5.2.1
Using ruby_parser 3.15.1
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using mustermann 1.1.1
Using thwait 0.2.0
Using sidekiq 6.2.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using activesupport 6.1.3.2
Using aws-sdk-core 3.114.0
Using simpleidn 0.2.1
Using et-orbi 1.2.4
Using faker 2.17.0
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using launchy 2.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using rspec-core 3.10.1
Using rspec-expectations 3.10.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.10.2
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using simplecov 0.21.2
Using sinatra 2.1.0
Using webmock 3.12.2
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using mini_mime 1.0.3
Using racc 1.5.2
Using ruby_http_client 3.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.11.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activemodel 6.1.3.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using aws-sdk-kms 1.43.0
Using dnsruby 1.61.5
Using factory_bot 6.1.0
Using fugit 1.4.5
Using sass 3.7.4
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using rspec 3.10.0
Using sendgrid-ruby 6.4.0
Using shoulda-matchers 4.5.1
Using simplecov-rcov 0.2.3
Using split 3.4.1
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using loofah 2.9.1
Using activejob 6.1.3.2
Using activerecord 6.1.3.2
Using aws-sdk-s3 1.93.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using html2haml 2.2.0
Using roo 2.8.3
Using rspec-wait 0.0.9
Using rufus-scheduler 3.7.0
Using webdrivers 4.6.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using sidekiq-scheduler 3.0.1
Using capybara 3.35.3
Using counter_culture 2.8.0
Using actionview 6.1.3.2
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.2.1
Using actionpack 6.1.3.2
Using kaminari-actionview 1.2.1
Using nonschema_migrations 5.0.2
Using actionmailer 6.1.3.2
Using railties 6.1.3.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using kaminari 1.2.1
Using activestorage 6.1.3.2
Using activerecord-session_store 2.0.0
Using font_awesome5_rails 1.4.0
Using actioncable 6.1.3.2
Using haml-rails 2.0.1
Using sass-rails 5.1.0
Using jquery-rails 4.4.0
Using rspec-rails 5.0.1
Using web-console 4.1.0
Using webpacker 5.2.1
Using actionmailbox 6.1.3.2
Using actiontext 6.1.3.2
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using responders 3.0.1
Using bootstrap 4.4.1
Using rails 6.1.3.2
Using factory_bot_rails 6.1.0
Using devise 4.7.3
Using turbo-rails 0.5.9 from https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails.git (at main@2945dcb)
Using stimulus-rails 0.2.3
Using stripe-rails 2.3.0
Using universal-track-manager 0.6.1.alpha
Using paranoia 2.4.3
Using spf-query 0.1.5 from https://github.com/trailofbits/spf-query.git (at master@6dac502)
Installing mysql2 0.5.3 with native extensions
Using hot-glue 0.1.1
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210604-8580-1kmtwzs.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /opt/homebrew/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... no
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
jason@MacBook-Air  %
```

I have already successfully run `brew install mysql` ... if I run it again it tells me:

Warning: mysql 8.0.25_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 8.0.25_1, run:
brew reinstall mysql

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Step 1**:

confirm you have both openssl and MySQL installed via brew

`brew install mysql`

`brew install openssl`

or if you have  previous version of openssl try

`brew reinstall openssl@3`

**Step 2**:

Run this on your Rails app to make sure you can get through bundler:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib
```

two things to note: `$(brew --prefix openssl)` dynamically replaces the stuff inside the evaluation `$(...)` to the directory of openssl on your machine.

`/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd` is really a **symlink** to the current version of zstd on your machine (which links to something like `/opt/homebrew/opt/Cellar/zstd/1.5.2`)

Also note, 0.5.3 is no longer the latest gem version for mysql2, find the latest version here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2

**Step 3**:

If you want this globally, run this:

```
bundle config --global build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib"
```

note that this will change your `~/.bundler/config` file and then applies globally to bundler

Comment: Thanks!

This worked for me on an M1 Mac with Big Sur!

Comment: Finally! After half-day of pulling my hair out, this worked for my M1 Big Sur. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me on Mac OS Monterey and a MacBook Pro with M1.

Comment: Bundler is at fault again... This have finally worked for me. Unbelievable, I wouldn't have thought. So much time wasted... Mac Big Sur Intel

Comment: Works M1 Mac, Monterey! One thing: `brew --prefix openssl` returns openssl@3 for me, but I have openssl@1.1 in homebrew/opt, so it errors with not found. For those having same issue, either `brew install openssl` to get the newer version or directly point to the version you have, in my case `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/`.

Comment: Rather than pointing at a specific version with `--with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib` use the symlinked dir which will point at whatever version you have: `--with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib`

Comment: On my machine, `/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib` was not the correct path, but `--with-ldflags=-L$(brew --prefix zstd)/lib` worked.

Comment: running `> echo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L(brew --prefix zstd)/lib`
gives `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3 -- --with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib` and runnign the command doesn't work, it errors out

Comment: I get `error: call to undeclared function 'rb_tainted_str_new2'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations`

Comment: `bundle config build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib"` worked for me (M2 Mac)

Answer (score 41):

Got the same error when try to install mysql2  -v 0.4.1 on M1 
--SOLVED--

```
brew install zstd

which zstd
```

my path is -> /opt/homebrew/bin/zstd 
you need to check where zstd linked from

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin
ls -la
```

zstd -> ../Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/bin/zstd 
so you need get path to zstd lib, my is:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib
```

And then do classic combination with some magic

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib"
bundle install

gem list my                                                                                                 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

mysql2 (0.4.10)
```

Comment: It worked just fine! Thank you so much!

Comment: this is a good example showing how to set this globally in homebrew; the accepted answer above should have a thorough walk through of all the steps and shows how to get it working with just `gem install` first, then once you confirm that works make the change globally to your bundler file

Comment: Thanks a bunch. it was starting to get on my nerves

Answer (score 20):

This is what worked for me on the M1.

First make sure you have mysql installed and openssl with Homebrew

```
brew install mysql
brew install openssl
```

Then set these values for the install of mysql2 manually. My path for zstd was the same as Octocats, so be sure to follow their instructions and change the --with-ldflags option appropriately.

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib""
```

Comment: does someone know the alternative for pip?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on the Apple M1

Answer (score 16):

This happened to me using MacOS 11.6 (Big Sur) on an M1 chip.

Try

```sh
brew install mysql
```

then

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix zstd)"
```

which worked for me.

If that works, then use this to configure Bundler to do it for you (in this directory, i.e. "local"):

```sh
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix zstd)""
```

Then `bundle install` should work.

Comment: this answer worked for me w/ openssl, e.g.:

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"`

but for some reason I can't get it to work when I use the bundle config command to save the setting

Comment: @subelsky are you using `bundle install` after you set the config for Bundler? `gem install` doesn't know anything about Bundler config. You can check what config is set using `bundle config list` in the directory containing your application's Gemfile.

Comment: that's a good point, I think I was in a rabbit hole trying to get that command to pass on its own

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle config --global build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib"
bundle install
```

As a solution to other problems as well, I have a `~/.bundle/config` with:

```
---
BUNDLE_JOBS: "9"
BUNDLE_BUILD__SQLITE3: "--with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration"
BUNDLE_BUILD__FFI: "--with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration"
BUNDLE_BUILD__MYSQL2: "--with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib"
```

And make sure you don't have anything in your local repo in `.bundle/config`

Answer (score 0):

On ruby 3.3.0 I configured it as follows:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 "--with-opt-dir="#(brew --prefix zstd)" --with-ldflags=-L"$(brew --prefix zstd)"/lib"
```

I had to set-up both `--with-opt-dir` and `--with-ldflags` and it worked.