# Couldn't install mysql2 0.5.3 in M1 MacBook Big Sur

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am trying to install mysql2 gem in MacBook M1 Big Sur, I am getting the the following errors.

```
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1
```

Full Error

```
Using mysql_config at /opt/homebrew/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... no
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/santosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried to install with different version of Ruby, nothing went well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840691/ld-library-not-found-for-lzstd-while-bundle-install-for-mysql2-gem-ruby-on-mac

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem too and I think what finally solved it was running:

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib`

However, for what it's worth, I'd previously installed without success but might have also been needed:

- homebrew, and `brew doctor` said it was `ready to brew`.
- Xcode tools `xcode-select --install`
- mysql  `brew install mysql` (and I could make a local connection)
- openssl `brew install openssl && brew link openssl --force`
- rbenv and `rbenv rehash`
- cmake `brew install cmake`

Comment: Just to consider you have to check the zstd version in my case it was 1.5.1 so the command for me was ``gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl) --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zstd/1.5.1/lib``

Comment: Phew, you did it!  That was way too hard lol.  I think the 0.5.3 version is important too for some reason.

Comment: This command alone fixed it in my case (MacOS Monterrey)!, different zstd version but worked anyway. Thank you sir!

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me on M1 with BigSur. My specific problem was resolved by this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68181856/5804379

Answer (score 16):

Apple Macbook air M1. Monterey. You need to install MySQL and openssl using `brew` .

This works for me.

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The simplest and most straight-forward solution out there.

Alternatively you can set this directly in your local bundle config:

`bundle config build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql`

Once you set this, all your bundle installs and updates of mysql should just work.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql2 0.5.6 (didn't work for previous versions) I was able to install it with the following command:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.6' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1) --with-ldflags=-L$(brew --prefix zstd)/lib
```

Trying to use brew --prefix whenever possible.

You can get more information in the README.md for the project [mysql2 gem README](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2?tab=readme-ov-file#mac-os-x)